# Angular6, http get returns undefined object

Tags: typescript, angular6

Well basically the problem is when trying to get an objet from a json file using its id as a parameter to find it. Everytime I want to get it from the json it's returned as an undefined object.

This is the component from which the service is beign used.  the object plato is the one that ends up beign undefined:

```
import { Plato } from 'src/app/plato';
import { PlatoService } from './../../../plato.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editar-plato',
  templateUrl: './editar-plato.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editar-plato.component.css']
})

export class EditarPlatoComponent implements OnInit {

  public plato: Plato;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private platoService: PlatoService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getPlato();
    console.log(this.plato);
  }

  private getPlato(){
    const id = ""+this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('nombre');
    this.platoService.getPlato(id)
    .subscribe(plato => this.plato = plato);
  }

}
```

The service is this one. I believe the problem is specifically in the  getPlato() function, but I havent been able to find why it always returns undefined:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Plato } from './plato';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PlatoService {

  private _url: string = "/assets/plato_data/platos.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,) { }

  getPlatos(): Observable<Plato[]>{
    return this.http.get<Plato[]>(this._url)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => console.log('fetched platos')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPlatos', []))
      );
  };

  getPlato(id: String): Observable<Plato>{
    return this.http.get<Plato>(this._url).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched plato id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Plato>(`getPlato id=${id}`))
    );
  }

    /*
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: you are not using the `id` in your `getPlato` method of service. you need to use HttpParams or direct querystring to filter the results, right now it will give `Plato[] ` instead of `Plato`

Comment: Just saw the comment a while ago and went to fix that, perfect, thank you for taking your time to answer this.